# Mobile UC Browser blocking CDN assets

Tags: http-headers, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, adblock

I have website setup to serve static files via CDN. I'm using cloudfront CDN. When i open my website on mobile using UC Browser. it only loads the HTML page and do not accepts the files(images,.js,.css, etc..) delivered by CDN.

However When I turn of CDN and serve files directly then my sites work without any problem. The problem occurs when ad-block mode is On in UC Browser.

about 80% visitors of my site uses UC browser and I don't want to turn off CDN. Also I've seen some websites that uses CDN and works fine in UC browser with ad-block mode turned On.

here are the headers returned by CDN for js file

```
age: 237446
cache-control: public, max-age=2592000
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: application/javascript
date: Mon, 24 Sep 2018 10:51:26 GMT
last-modified: Sat, 15 Sep 2018 08:56:57 GMT
server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
status: 200
vary: Accept-Encoding
via: 1.1 b5fbf0f0a39109b04a248c9bb51b5d6a.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: IoyQ_74Qgo9nqBRJN0YHkTZk-atMfRscw50y27LxPiMuUG0VeQUxHA==
x-cache: Hit from cloudfront`
```

Comment: facing same issue. did you find any solution?